# App script - upload CSV or XLS file from Drive to Bigquery or Spreadsheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I created this code for upload CSV file to spreadsheet and then to BQ.

```
function appendCSV() {  
 var arryFileDates,file,fileDate,files,folder,folders,
      newestDate,newestFileID,objFilesByDate;

  folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Shipments file').next(); 
  
   files = folder.getFiles()
 var max_file = files.next()
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    
    if(file.getName() > max_file.getName() ){
    
      max_file = file
    }
  }
  
 

  
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(max_file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet5")
      
  sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  
  }
```

But unfortunately, I got the following result.
when I upload the same file from Google Bigquery interface it's working well (the file contains 5 columns and 50 rows).

[image]

I also tried to upload the file to BQ directly :
and get the same prob

```
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 5, but line starting at position:9 contains only 1 columns.

function loadCsv(csvFileId) {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'nerivio-datascience';
  // Create a dataset in the BigQuery UI (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com)
  // and enter its ID below.
  var datasetId = 'Upload';
  var tableId = 'Shipments file'
 var csvFileId = csvFileId;

//  // Create the table.
//  var tableId = 'pets_' + new Date().getTime();
//  var table = {
//    tableReference: {
//      projectId: projectId,
//      datasetId: datasetId,
//      tableId: tableId
//    },
//    schema: {
//      fields: [
//        {name: 'week', type: 'STRING'},
//        {name: 'cat', type: 'INTEGER'},
//        {name: 'dog', type: 'INTEGER'},
//        {name: 'bird', type: 'INTEGER'}
//      ]
//    }
//  };
//  table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
//  Logger.log('Table created: %s', table.id);

  // Load CSV data from Drive and convert to the correct format for upload.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(csvFileId);
  var data = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');

  // Create the data upload job.
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1
      }
    }
  };
  job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  Logger.log('Load job started. Check on the status of it here: ' +
      'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', projectId);
}
```

Comment: I think you may have a typo after your while loop. A ")".

Comment: No, is not show on my code, this is a mistake I made when I copy my code

Comment: I printed the file type and get "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" is this make a difference?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your csv file?, and if you can tell which line the code is failing it would help.